# Способы ограничения доступа к директориям проекта

Tags: php

Кто знает библиотеки/функции которые могли бы запретить доступ к определённым директориям сайта?

**Предыстория** - в проекте есть куча папок бекенда (всё вперемешку с фронтом), в некоторых по понятным причинам юзерам делать нечего. Так вот в каждой из ник создавать файлы .htaccess с правилами - не вариант ибо директорий много, а сеять хаос не хочется (что я понял только сейчас). Сейчас всё работает так - есть код собственной разработки)) который занимается автоматическим созданием файлов .htaccess в нужных директориях, если они отсутствуют. Но беда в том что много copy past'ы которая занимается одним и тем же, только пути разные. Я думаю о не ликвидности текущего решения говорить не приходиться...

**Ближе к сути** - мне нужно компактное решение в биде библиотеки/функции, которое
примерно по такому синтаксису `bouncer_dir("full path to dir1", "full path to dir2", "full path to dir3")` будет ограничивать доступ к папкам. Неважно как, пусть создаёт htaccess с одинаковыми правилами, если других вариантов нету.

**Если кто знает решение в виде функции, библиотеки или просто может дать совет, то - буду признателен**

Comment: А сделать по-человевечески и сделать реструктуризацию и отделение мух от котлет вы не хотите?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, я бы с радостью, но тут это не подразумевается... Легаси конкретный (PHP 5.5)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, очень много рефакторить надо, мне легче quick fix вставить

Comment: Ну так напишите функцию, которая пробежится по всем каталогам и вставит файл htaccess по шаблону

Comment: @ArchDemon, если это кто-то до меня написал, так ещё и в более хорошей форме наверняка, то зачем делать велосипед? В любом случае я накидал пару возможных вариантов реализации, но нету уверенности в корректности и эффективности моего решения.

Comment: Чтобы не делать велосипед, нужно прочитать первый комментарий и сделать как там сказано. Других решений нет и не будет

Comment: @ArchDemon, хорошо. Я вас понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
    function htAccessWrite( $paths = [] ) {
        $result = false;
        if ( is_array( $paths ) && count( $paths ) > 0 ) {
            foreach( $paths as $path ) {
                $path .= ( mb_substr( $path, mb_strlen($path) - 1, 1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '' );
                if ( !is_null($path) && trim($path) != "" && ( realpath( trim($path) ) !== false AND is_dir( realpath( trim($path) ) ) ) && is_writeable( $path ) ) {
                    //Файл уже существует?
                    if ( file_exists($path . '.htaccess') ) {
                        //Открываем его на чтение - смотрим нет ли уже в нем наших инструкций - если нет дописываем - если есть - пропускаем файл
                    } else {
                        //Файла не существует - пишем в него наши инструкции доступа
                        $fp = @fopen('.htaccess', 'w');
                        if ( $fp ) {
                            fwrite($fp, ''); //пишем в файл нужные иинструкции
                            fclose($fp);
                        }
                    } 
                    $result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

```php
    htAccessWrite(['/var/www/myproject.yii/web/storage/folder1', '/var/www/myproject.yii/web/storage/folder2', '/var/www/myproject.yii/web/storage/folder3']);
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Как я понял, вы этот сниппет выцепили из движка vii? (Исходя из пути).

Comment: Я этот `snippet` написал за 5 минут :)

Comment: сниппет неплохой, проверки есть на все случаи жизни)) Есть вопрос один, почему вы сразу не написали условие `if` c `!file_exists`, а написали `file_exists`? Я просто интересуюсь, может я чего то не понимаю

Comment: Потому что у Вас может два условия - первое, файл `.htaccess` в директории уже существует - тогда Вам нужно проверить его на наличие в нем нужных Вам инструкций, а второй - когда его нет - тогда тупо создаем его с нуля. В коде же все написано.

Comment: У нас тело условия if пустое, следовательно если файл есть, то ничего не происходит, как и надо. Но можно же написать сразу if(!file_exists), и в него вставить код который создаёт файл, если файла нету. Если же файл есть, то ничего не произойдёт, записи не будет, ибо стоит одно условие, которое работает только на запись если файла нету. По итогу кода станет меньше, а функционал - тот же

Comment: А если у Вас в директории уже лежит файл созданный ранее, но не Вами? Вы его пропустите. А в нем нет условий ограничивающих доступ. Поэтому я и разделил код на две ветки - и даже написал комментарий - если существует - проверяйте есть ли в нем нужные Вам ограничения. Если же Вам эта ветка не нужна - сократите код. Целиком задачу-то только Вы знаете :)

Comment: Хорошо, теперь кажется дошло 